# Porting enterprise one reports from Crystal Reports to JasperReports framework

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports, peoplesoft

My employer is considering migrating our e1 reporting from crystal reports 10 to another solution.

I want to use jasper server and I was wondering if there is a standard migration path or standard report package that we could use to make the task easier/faster. Also, any experience shared about creating the user objects for jasper business intelligence portal would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting for my employer too.
I researched a lot about it, it seems there is no way to do achieve this in a (semi) automatic approach.

I'm currently working in my own Report Generator, to replace Crystal Reports in my company.

Let me know it it interest you.